# Memory allocation first time compilation error on terminal

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, makefile, malloc

I am working on a malloc lab program where i need to find the performance index of utility and throughput. I am able to get the output efficiency but there is one problem when executing  for the first time.

I have given specific set of files which includes traces and other files,When i am trying to run the program first time it is showing errors but when i run the same code with same command second time to multiple times i am not getting error and output is fine? why it is showing error in when running first time ? is there any problem with allocating memory or performing operation in malloc ?

the commands and first time error as follows ,

```
enter code here
@ubuntu:$ make
```

when i run this first time i am getting error which is as follows ,

```
enter code here
gcc -Wall -O2 -m32   -c -o mdriver.o mdriver.c
mdriver.c: In function ‘remove_range’:
mdriver.c:438:9: warning: variable ‘size’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
 int size;
     ^
mdriver.c: In function ‘read_trace’:
mdriver.c:498:11: warning: ignoring return value of ‘fscanf’, declared with attribute   warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
 fscanf(tracefile, "%d", &(trace->sugg_heapsize)); /* not used */
       ^
mdriver.c:499:11: warning: ignoring return value of ‘fscanf’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
fscanf(tracefile, "%d", &(trace->num_ids));     
       ^
mdriver.c:500:11: warning: ignoring return value of ‘fscanf’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
fscanf(tracefile, "%d", &(trace->num_ops));     
       ^
mdriver.c:501:11: warning: ignoring return value of ‘fscanf’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
fscanf(tracefile, "%d", &(trace->weight));        /* not used */
       ^
mdriver.c:524:12: warning: ignoring return value of ‘fscanf’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
fscanf(tracefile, "%u %u", &index, &size);
        ^
mdriver.c:531:12: warning: ignoring return value of ‘fscanf’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
fscanf(tracefile, "%u %u", &index, &size);
        ^
mdriver.c:538:12: warning: ignoring return value of ‘fscanf’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
fscanf(tracefile, "%ud", &index);
        ^
gcc -Wall -O2 -m32   -c -o mm.o mm.c
mm.c:780:13: warning: ‘mm_check’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
static int mm_check(void)
         ^
gcc -Wall -O2 -m32   -c -o memlib.o memlib.c
gcc -Wall -O2 -m32   -c -o fsecs.o fsecs.c
gcc -Wall -O2 -m32   -c -o fcyc.o fcyc.c
gcc -Wall -O2 -m32   -c -o clock.o clock.c
gcc -Wall -O2 -m32   -c -o ftimer.o ftimer.c
gcc -Wall -O2 -m32 -o mdriver mdriver.o mm.o memlib.o fsecs.o fcyc.o clock.o ftimer.o
```

I run the same command again

```
enter code here
@ubuntu:$ make
make: `mdriver' is up to date.
```

Now then it shows no error and after that if i run the program with the required commands it works perfectly fine ,but it is showing errors first time ?

Comment: You have two options: (a) fix the code that is producing the warnings, (b) disable the warnings.   If you choose (b) be prepared to bear the consequences :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no error in your source. There are many warnings. The object and executable files will be generated even source is having warnings. In makefile, the files will not be recompiled if the timestamp is remains same.

For more understanding, tiger some compilation error in your source and run `make` command again and again then you can understand the difference.

Comment: the error are coming from a file called mdriver.c which is given by my professor and i don't have to modify it ,thing is i am really confused how to get rid of those warnings !! i tried to change something in make file but it didn't help me !!

Comment: @Dvlop try make -s. it will supers the print. then share the error message .As of now i cant find error message in your posting. Try to simplify your issue and post again.